# how to make a query to add value in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm just learned how to make database here. So i have a project to make database for item inventory and i'm using phpmyadmin. My problem is, i want value in column 'quantity' is add by value in column 'jumlah_masuk' and minus by value i column 'jumlah_keluar' then the result will be in column 'saldo_akhir'.

i've done this query:

```
SELECT *, (quantity+jumlah_masuk)-jumlah_keluar FROM dbinventory.tbbarang;
 UPDATE tbbarang SET saldo_akhir=(quantity+jumlah_masuk)-jumlah_keluar WHERE ID_barang
```

and i got this outcome:

```
 quantity   jumlah_masuk   jumlah_keluar  saldo_akhir
 --------   ------------   -------------  -----------
  100           50               25           125
```

and i did it. but, if i want to make an input of new item. the value from 'quantity','jumlah_masuk','jumlah_keluar' the query not executed.

what i want is everytime i'm input new item, the value from column 'quantity' and so on will be executed automatically.

so what should i do ?

Comment: Why store the results of the formula when it can be calculated anytime you run a query?That's a lot more reliable and less intensive on the server than setting up insert and update triggers to keep the result and store it in a column. If you really want to do it, you will need to create two triggers, on for after insert and another for after update. Lookup triggers for syntax and examples

Answer (score 1):

Rather than triggers, a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) is a good solution.

```
ALTER TABLE tbbarang DROP saldo_akhir,
  ADD saldo_akhir INT AS (quantity + jumlah_masuk - jumlah_keluar)
```

Comment: i just tried that query, but the calculation is store in 'quantity' column. I Want the result will be store in 'saldo_akhir' column @danblack